# I am trying to use GET without using Sockets and I keep getting 400 Bad Request

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, get

I found an example here but I keep getting the following error,  I have tried various combinations in the header to no avail... Postman requests work fine.  I am missing something... This is a 443 port... Do I need to use another method? As you will discover reading on I am not familiar with making HTTPS requests but need to add this to my software to pull recent data from a server.  Any assistance would be appreciated...

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Mon, 25 May 2020 16:52:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 236
Connection: close

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;
using std::string;

... 


    // Initialize Dependencies to the Windows Socket.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        fprintf(fpSessionLog,"WSAStartup failed.\n");
        fflush(fpSessionLog);
        goto SKIP;
    }

    // We first prepare some "hints" for the "getaddrinfo" function
    // to tell it, that we are looking for a IPv4 TCP Connection.
    struct addrinfo hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;          // We are targeting IPv4
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;    // We are targeting TCP
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    // We are targeting TCP so its SOCK_STREAM

    // Aquiring of the IPv4 address of a host using the newer
    // "getaddrinfo" function which outdated "gethostbyname".
    // It will search for IPv4 addresses using the TCP-Protocol.
    struct addrinfo* targetAdressInfo = NULL;
    DWORD getAddrRes = getaddrinfo("api-thisSite.com", NULL, &hints, &targetAdressInfo);
    if (getAddrRes != 0 || targetAdressInfo == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fpSessionLog,"Could not resolve the Host Name\n");
        fflush(fpSessionLog);
        WSACleanup();
        goto SKIP;
    }

    // Create the Socket Address Informations, using IPv4
    // We dont have to take care of sin_zero, it is only used to extend the length of SOCKADDR_IN to the size of SOCKADDR
    SOCKADDR_IN sockAddr;
    sockAddr.sin_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in*) targetAdressInfo->ai_addr)->sin_addr;    // The IPv4 Address from the Address Resolution Result
    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;  // IPv4
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(443);  

    // We have to free the Address-Information from getaddrinfo again
    freeaddrinfo(targetAdressInfo);

    // Creation of a socket for the communication with the Web Server,
    // using IPv4 and the TCP-Protocol
    SOCKET webSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (webSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        fprintf(fpSessionLog,"Creation of the Socket Failed\n");
        fflush(fpSessionLog);
        WSACleanup();
        goto SKIP;
    }

    // Establishing a connection to the web Socket
    //cout << "Connecting...\n";
    fprintf(fpSessionLog,"Connecting...\n");
    fflush(fpSessionLog);

    if(connect(webSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) != 0)
    {
       fprintf(fpSessionLog,"Could not connect!\n");
       fflush(fpSessionLog);
       closesocket(webSocket);
       WSACleanup();
       goto SKIP;
    }
    fprintf(fpSessionLog,"Connected!\n");
    fflush(fpSessionLog);

    // Sending a HTTP-GET-Request to the Web Server  
    const char* httpRequest = "GET /api/v1/ecm HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api-thisSite.com\r\nX-Authorization: {api key goes here}\r\nAccept: application/json"
    fprintf(fpSessionLog,"Formulated Server Request: %s \n",httpRequest);
    fflush(fpSessionLog);
    int sentBytes = send(webSocket, httpRequest, strlen(httpRequest),0);
    if (sentBytes < strlen(httpRequest) || sentBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        //cout << "Could not send the request to the Server" << endl;
        //system("pause");
        fprintf(fpSessionLog,"Could not send the request to the Server!\n");
        fflush(fpSessionLog);
        closesocket(webSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        goto SKIP;
    }

    // Receiving and Displaying an answer from the Web Server
    char buffer[10000];
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    int dataLen;
    while ((dataLen = recv(webSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) > 0))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            //cout << buffer[i];
            fprintf(fpSessionLog,"%c",buffer[i]);
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    fflush(fpSessionLog);

    // Cleaning up Windows Socket Dependencies
    closesocket(webSocket);
    WSACleanup();









    SKIP:
```

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Mon, 25 May 2020 20:32:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 236
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I send an HTTPS request to an HTTPS port?

Comment: You will not be able to write your own HTTPS implementation in any reasonable amount of time. Use an existing library. Windows comes with two of them - [WinInet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/about-wininet) and [WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/about-winhttp). Either is capable of sending HTTPS requests.

Comment: HTTPS is more than just connecting on TCP port 443. Much, much, much, much, more. You have to implement the TLS protocol. All 100 pages of it.

Comment: Thanks,  I git it working with WinINet...